# Search on keyup and document ready using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make search function based on Ajax/Jquery.

My web app shows the data of service requests from the database. I want to make searchbar for my app as follows:

1. show all service request on the table initially.
2. If something is typed on the searchbar, it searches data and load those data to the table.
3. Finally if user deletes anyword from searchbar it will show all data as stated on No.1

I managed doing second and third function but I am having issues with the first one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){  
        var txt = $(this).val();  
        if(txt != '') {  
            $.ajax({  
                url:"ajax/fetchRequests.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{search:txt},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data) {  
                    $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
            });  
        }
        else if(txt == '') {  
            $.get("ajax/readRequests.php", {}, function (data, status) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is another script that i have worked on trying:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var txt = $('#search_text').val();

    if(txt != ''){
        $.ajax({  
            url:"ajax/fetchRequests.php",  
            method:"post",  
            data:{search:txt},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data) {  
                $('#result').html(data);  
            }  
        });  
    }
    else if(txt == '') {  
        $.get("ajax/readRequests.php", {}, function (data, status) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });                 
    }  
});
```

All my features are working except for the search functions. Any tips or critics are welcome, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: assuming `txt` is a string, you should just use `if(txt)` to check if that is either empty or null (it evaluates to false in both the cases).....Also, it is better to stick to strict equality checks in case you want to mute implicit type conversions....

Comment: try ...
$('#search_text').on('keyup', function(){
//your code here
}); instead of  $('#search_text').keyup(function(){

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you Omasu, taking a closer look at it right now :)

Comment: Tried it and also tried other methods by looking at website. Still having same results. Can't see whole table in the beginning

Comment: What isn't working? You don't say what issues you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do two things, 1) use the suggested `.on()` and 2) use only one ajax function to simplify things. The idea is to funnel your calls through one function so that you know if something fails, it's not because you messed up the ajax part of the script:

```
// Create a generic ajax function so you can easily re-use it
function fetchResults($,path,method,data,func)
    {
        $.ajax({  
            url: path,  
            type: method,  
            data: data,  
            success:function(response) {
                func(response);
            }
        }); 
    }
// Create a simple function to return your proper path
function getDefaultPath(type)
    {
        return 'ajax/'+type+'Requests.php';
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    // When the document is ready, run the read ajax
    fetchResults($, getDefaultPath('read'), 'post', false, function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
    });
    // On keyup
    $(this).on('keyup','#search_text',function(){
        // Get the value either way
        var getText =   $(this).val();
        // If empty, use "read" else use "fetch"
        var setPath =   (!getText)? 'read' : 'fetch';
        // Choose method, though I think post would be better to use in both instances...
        var type    =   (!getText)? 'post' : 'get';
        // Run the keyup function, this time with dynamic arguments
        fetchResults($, getDefaultPath(setPath), type, { search: getText },function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, never thought of this way. Really changed my view, now its time for a deeper research :)

Answer (score 1):

To get initial results hook onto jQuery's document ready event.

```
var xhr;
var searchTypingTimer;

$(document).ready(function(){
    // initial load of results
    fetchResults([put your own params here]);

    // apply on change event
    $('#search_text').on('input', function() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        searchTypingTimer = setTimeout(fetchResults, 300);
    });
});

function fetchResults($,path,method,data,func)
{
    if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
        xhr.abort();
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({  
        url: path,  
        type: method,  
        data: data,  
        success:function(response) {
            func(response);
        }
    }); 
}
```

As Rasclatt mentions you should use jQuery's on method to catch any changes. 
Secondly I'd recommend disposing of previous requests when you make new ones, since if you are sending a new one on each character change then for one word many requests will be made. They won't necessarily arrive back in the order you send them. So for example as you type 'search term', the result for 'search ter' may arrive after and replace 'search term'. (welcome to async).

Thirdly since you will send many requests in quick succession I'd only call your fetchResults function after a short time out, so for example if a user types a five character word it doesn't fire until 300ms after the last character is typed. This will prevent 4 unnecessary requests that would just be ignored but put strain on your backend.

Comment: Thank you, havent really considered about unnecessary request. Didnt really think it would put strain :P thank you for the tips!